# locating file in a classpath

Tags: java

I'm trying to read in file content, ex :

```
public void myMethod(){
     FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
     String strLine;
     while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
....
....
.....
end while 
end method
```

And I have at the begining of the class body `private String fileLocation;` and at the end of a class I have a getter and setter for it. Now I'm trying inject this file location from spring inside bean from this class and I specify the init-method of this class. But I get error cannot find the specified file as if its not on a classpath but it is inside war file? I'm building the project with maven and I put file in `src/main/resources` This is the error I get when trying to read file :

> Error: src\main\resources\ids.txt
>   (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)

That is when I tried this :

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("src\\main\\resources\\ids.txt");
```

how to reference the properly from the classpath?

**EDIT**

When I edit my code according to @BalusC solution , here is how it looks but I still get `null` error :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); 
   InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/ids.txt");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
   String strLine;
 while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    ....
    ....
    .....
    end while 
    end method
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Java IO API relies on the local disk file system, not on the classpath. Besides, using relative paths in Java IO stuff is recipe for portability trouble, don't rely on it. To allocate resources in the classpath you would normally use [`ClassLoader#getResource()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or  [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/ids.txt");
```

That said, you don't need that `DataInputStream` line. You're actually not taking any benefit from it.

**Update**: if that doesn't work, then either the resource name is simply invalid or the file is actually not there in the classpath where you expect it to be. My cents on that the `src` folder is actually the **root** of the classpath and not part of a package. Remove it from the name.

**Update 2**: to get all root disk file system paths which are covered by the runtime classpath do:

```
for (URL root : Collections.list(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources(""))) {
    System.out.println(root);
}
```

The resource name needs to be relative to either of them. That it is been placed in `/WEB-INF/classes` during the build is normal. It is covered by the classpath. Your problem lies somewhere else. Are you sure that the resource name is correct? Are you sure that you're running the code you think you are running?

Comment: @BalusC its same I get null when I remove the `src` bit, I've just looked inside target war which is deployed on jboss inside this file is location inside `WEB-INF/classes` but in my project in eclipse its located in `src/main/resources` any other tricks up your sleeve?

Comment: @BalusC can I perhaps see where this class loader has gone into, into which folder or ..

Comment: @BalusC that is great news I found what needs to be done by using that for loop. I needed to put only `ids.txt` and that is enough for reading it. Thanks a million