# Where to place the configuration files that should be readable by the jar file in dynamic java project?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem locating file in a classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666875/problem-locating-file-in-a-classpath)

Where should the configuration files like xml file should be placed in the java dynamic web project in the case, where the external jar file in the lib folder should read the configuration file at runtime.

Comment: timestamp of both question & answer is 2012-08-22 11:14:24Z

Comment: @Sunny You are right, that is an option in stackoverflow when we ask question. As I struggled for sometime to find this I have done like this which may be useful for someone in future.

Comment: I voted to close as this has been answered over and over again...

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is that these files must arrive to you application classpath. In case of web probject `WEB-INF/classes` is the best location. (as already mentioned  by @Easwaramoorthy Kanaga).

The question is where to put the files in project. 
If you are using maven it almost dictates the location `src/main/resources`. If you are not with maven put them to resources directory anyway. The resources directory should be defined on the same level as `src` directory. For example if you have `src` directory under your project root create `resources` directory at the same place. Configure your IDE to copy these files to target directory. Update your build script to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can place it in the WEB-INF/classes folder. Even you can place a folder inside the classes folder which will work perfectly.

One more thing, The jar file should read the config file with a hardcoded path, instead it should do like this.

```
String xmlFilePath = "configfile.xml";    
InputStream file = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xmlFilePath);
```

Comment: Consider marking your answer as the correct one.