# Location of config.properties file in Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration-files, properties-file

I am trying to read the config.properties file (located in my project root, with my pom.xml, README.md,...). However, I always got "FileNotFound" exceptions. Where should I locate this file in order to work with this code?

**/src/main/java/com.example.proj.db/DatabaseManager.java**

```
public DatabaseManager() throws IOException {
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  InputStream input = null;

  input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
  prop.load(input);
  dbUser = prop.getProperty("dbUser");
}
```

**config.properties**

```
# Database Configuration
dbuser=wooz
```

Comment: Typically, I would say /src/main/resources/ as a starting location <_<

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work from that location either, @Compass. Same error.

Comment: Try `getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")` (in combination with the suggestion @Compass gave)

Comment: If I were you, I'd rather load the file as a classpatch resource. I'd put it in /src/main/resources/, as @Compass already mentioned, and then load it by `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I typically do:

1. Put the property file in /src/main/resources, as mentioned by @Compass
2. Do a resource filtering in build section of pom.xml to make sure the property file is copied into the package.

   ```
   <build>
       ...
       <resources>
           <resource>
               <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
           </resource>
       </resources>
       ...
   </build>
   ```
3. Since I'm using Spring to load a property file, I simply write the file path as "classpath:config.properties". But you may need to resort some other technique, such as [locating file in a classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666875/locating-file-in-a-classpath)